# PhoneGap/Cordova: How to add PHP support?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I just read that it is indeed possible to use PHP. My question is how to add such support? Is there an API's or plug-ins to add PHP support?

In short, I want to use PhoneGap alongside PHP to develop apps. How?

**Specifics**

- I'll use a Linux server & hosting with godaddy, to park my PHP.
- In addition, I'll use MySQL database
- The app will send database requests to that server.
- The server will be sending large amount of data back to the app.

What would be the most efficient "light weight" method to "transfer the data" and requests between the app and server/hosting account?

Comment: You [can't use PHP](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/) in a Phonegap app.

Comment: @Timo is right. Your only way to interact with a server is via external web services. Here's what's written in the documentation `However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://phonegap.com/about/faq/. The last FAQ reads:

**Q: Can you use PHP/ASP/JSF/Java/.NET with PhoneGap?**

> A: A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
>   However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web
>   Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in
>   any language. This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access
>   existing business processes while the device is connected to the
>   Internet.

To be a little more clear, If you want to use PHP, it will be on the server, and the server will NOT run on the mobile device (phone/tablet). Again, your PHP server will run in the cloud, NOT on the phone.

Comment: I read the same FAQ, but it was not clear to me how to do it. It is still not clear since you're using the same source :p

Comment: Would u mind expanding it a bit more and some samples if possible?

Comment: @Omar, samples of this would take too much time and are beyond the scope of this forum.  However,  I cannot be any clearer. To use PHP, the PHP will run on a server that uses Intel. PHP will NOT RUN ON ANY MOBILE DEVICES, either a phone or a tablet. Phonegap and other mobile frameworks (Unity, Ionic, Swift, XCode) do NOT HAVE a server. When you write for mobile devices you are writing an APP. PHP is server technology. PHP supports mobile devices on the network -- NOT on the mobile device. --------- I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Thanks. About "samples" I guess I asked the question wrong. I have a hosting account with godaddy and can park my PHP there. What would be the most efficient "light weight" method to "transfer the data" to the app and vice versa? To be more specific, I'll be sending and requesting database data and HTML code as well. -A sample along those lines

Comment: That's simple enough, use *Jquery, Angular, Ember* or any Javascript library that offer a REST interface. *Google* [phonegap REST API](https://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap+REST+API)  Then implement your PHP web server with a REST interface. *Google* [php REST API](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+REST+API)